# Скрипт на питоне не видит пакеты виртуального окружения

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

Создал виртуальное окружение пакета virtualenv командой:

```
python -m venv env
```

Активирую его

```
env\Scritpt\activate.bat
```

Появляется имя окружения в скобках. 
Устанавливаю Фласк

```
pip install flask
```

Он устанавливается, далее, создаю файл Hello.py в папке проекта (на одном уровне с env-папкой). Но импортировать фласк не могу, пишется ошибка - нет модуля.

Comment: pip -V покажет точный путь к dist-packages в который инсталит пакеты (там же и путь к текущему интерпритатору)

Comment: Кем пишется? Тот, кто пишет ошибку, был уведомлён вами о том, что виртуальное окружение вообще существует?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что при создании проекта путь до интерпретатора отличался от пути до окружения. Они должны ссылаться в одно и то же место.